# How to import a .csv as an array in python

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before, but for this specific example I don't understand why it is not working:

```
import csv

    with open('ThruputCSV.csv') as csvfile: 
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        v = []
        for row in readCSV: 
            v = row[1]

            v.append(v)
```

The error message that I get is 'str' object has no attribute  append

The csv file that I import, however, has 10 rows and 2 columns and in the second column there are float values. I want to work with these float values. I want to store them as a vector and I figured this code should do exactly that

Answer (score 2):

Remove `v = row[1]` and change to this:

```
>>> v.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [c[1] for c in list(readCSV)] # don't overcomplicate things.
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Hardly surprising you are using v for two things. General point: when setting variables try to make sure you only use them for one thing.